# Why “to” is here in this sentence? “please to ring the bell”

Tags: infinitives

Among songs from Wee Sing for Baby, there is a song “To Babyland”

The lyrics begin as:

> How many miles to Babyland?
>   Anyone can tell: Up one flight, to the right.
>   Please to ring the bell”

I am not an English native and I think the lyric is right grammatically because it is written by English native. But I don’t know why “please to ~~” is used. I have learned that “please ring the bell” is right.

And on more question.
“up one flight” - here “flight” means “floor”??
(a dictionary says)
Is the 2-3rd line sentences mean “ If you go up one floor
and go to the right, you will find a door and you should ring the bell on the door.”?? Do I understand well??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't assume everything written by native English speakers is grammatically correct. Also in song lyrics sometimes the wording can be a bit strange in order to match the rhythm of the melody.

Comment: The Google nGram in the accepted answer to a similar question shows that the _please to + infinitive_ construction has steadily declined in use since the beginning of the 19th century. That said, as noted by @nnnnnn all rules are off when it comes to verse, and in the present case _please ring the bell_ sounds rather too prosaic and makes for a less pleasing rhythm. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61735/is-please-to-proper-english

Comment: Please only ask about one thing per post. 1. "Please to ring the bell" 2. "Up one flight"

Comment: See [this earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61735/is-please-to-proper-english) . It is old-fashioned usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "Please to" proper English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61735/is-please-to-proper-english) See also [Is “please to remind” a valid construction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118493/is-please-to-remind-a-valid-construction)